# Fubini-Tonelli to show sum converges almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $r_n$ be an enumeration of the rationals. Using Fubini-Tonelli show that,

$$ F(x) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|r_n-x|}} $$

is finite almost everywhere.

I suppose one has to rewrite the sum as an integral and then do some interchanging using Fubini-Tonelli, but am not sure about the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you leave the sum as a sum, but you integrate it over $x$ in some interval $[a,b]$.  Use Fubini-Tonelli to change the integral of the sum to the sum of the integrals, and estimate...

Comment: Ah yes of course. Way easier than I thought actually. I must be tired a bit... or I was thrown off by the Fubini-Tonelli reference. I know the "swap theorem" as a simple consequence of the monotone convergence theorem, how does it relate to Fubini-Tonelli?

Comment: @Jori Take one of the two measures to be [counting measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure), then the "swap theorem" is a corollary of Fubini-Tonelli.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:F(x)=\infty\}$. To show that $m(E)=0$, it's enough to show that $m(E\cap[-N,N])=0$
for all integers $N\geq 1$, and to prove this, it's enough to show that $\int_{-N}^NF(x)\;dx<\infty$ for each $N\geq 1$.

It follows from Tonelli's theorem (or the monotone convergence theorem) that
$$ \int_{-N}^NF(x)\;dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\int_{-N}^N\frac{1}{\sqrt{|r_n-x|}}\;dx$$
and therefore all that's left is the (somewhat tedious) task of bounding the integrals $\int_{-N}^N\frac{dx}{\sqrt{|r_n-x|}}$.

Comment: In fact we only need to prove $m(E\cap[0+N,1+N])=0$, and by symmetry $m(E\cap[0,1])=0$ is enough. So we only need to bound $\int_0^1 dx/\sqrt{|r_n-x|}$, which is very easy task.

Comment: Each of those integrals is bounded by $2\int_0^N x^{-1/2}\,dx = 4\sqrt N.$